# Incredible graphic glitch

Tags: gpu

I tried to watch a video on Youtube, on HD. the very moment I hit play, my screen enters the matrix :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmDPLUnbnZI

I immediately reset, and my screen now blinked like it was about to die. used some built-in LCD conditioning and it fixed temporary. I get that blinking sometimes after the incident.

Also, when working on eg : Photoshop (cs6), I get frequent glitches that look like this :

[image: Photo of screen problem]

I am highly aware that this is probably a GPU issue. Before going for something else, I'd like to see if anyone has any info on what might cause this.

Windows 7
AMD RADEON HD 7970
DELL U2412M - (also occured on another monitor)

Comment: try updating the GPU driver and run GPU benchmark tools and look if they also cause such glitches

Comment: drivers up to date, benchmarked with 3DMark.

Comment: Whoa.... that looks like some cool art...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a serious problem with your GPU. Many GPUs do these kinds of "glitches" right before they are about to die or burn out.

Your problem is probably caused by overheating. Try removing the card, blowing all of the dust out with a compressed gas can (have a vacuum cleaner at the ready). Use your finger as well to reach some parts; on my card, you have to pull out the dust, as it accumulates from *inside* the case and sometimes even completely blocks the airflow in the card.

If this did not solve the issue, your card is most likely fried. Sorry about that.

Comment: [Reflowing](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/56202-35-what-reflow-laptop-repair) could help too.